# Appending list items to another list randomly

Tags: python

I am making Blackjack for a college assignment and I need to append 2 random cards from the deck to the player list (his hand).

this is my code so far.

```
import random
import time

Ace=1
Jack=10
Queen=10
King=10

deck=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"Ace","Jack","Queen","King"]
player=[]
dealer=[]



def welcome():
    start=input("Hi there - Fancy a game of Blackjack? yes or no ")
    if start == "yes":
        print ("The game will begin now...")
        time.sleep(2)
        startgame()

def startgame():
    print ("Dealing...")
    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range (2):
        player = random.randint(1,13)
        print (player)





welcome()
startgame()
```

thank you

Shaun

Comment: Add the code to question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you do in a real game of cards? You don't pick random numbers and see what card corresponds to that number and whether it's already taken. You just `shuffle` the deck and then `pop` cards from the deck into the players' hands.

```
>>> cards = list(range(52)) # your actual cards    
>>> random.shuffle(cards)
>>> hand = [cards.pop() for _ in range(5)] # pop first 5 card from shuffled deck
>>> hand
[29, 34, 25, 3, 46]
```

This is closest to real-life and also guarantees that no cards are taken twice. You can use the same approach for dealing more cards: Just call `pop` again from the still shuffled deck and add the card to the respective hand.

Comment: Looks like you're working with Python 2, while OP is using Python 3. He'll need to pass `range(52)` to a `list()` call first.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like

```
hand=[]
for i in range(2):
  card=random.choice(deck)
  hand.append(card)
  deck.pop(card)
```

This will give you a hand of 2 cards, and make sure you cant duplicate cards. It is important to re-create deck such that it has all 52 cards again at the start of every game, or adapt the logic so that it is something more like:

```
hand=[]
for i in range(2):
  card=random.choice(deck)
  if card in hand: #Note you will need to check every hand here
    continue
  else:
    hand.append(card)
```